# static Comparator Collections.reverseOrder(Comarator) showing warning

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class pqr
{
public static void main(String ab[])
{
List<Integer> ts=new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
ts.add((int)(Math.random()*1000));
System.out.println(ts);

class RSO implements Comparator<Integer>
{
public int compare(Integer i,Integer j)
{
return j-i;
}
}
RSO rs=new RSO();
Collections.sort(ts,rs);
System.out.println(ts);

Comparator fs=(Comparator<Integer>)Collections.reverseOrder(rs); // Same result with casting or without casting
Collections.sort(ts,fs);
System.out.println(ts);
}
}
```

This code is giving me the expected result but while compiling it's showing the following
warning message for the 5th line from the end :

```
Note: 5.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I am getting same warning with or without casting, please help me removing the warning.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not the cast, it's the fact that you're assigning it to a raw `Comparator` reference.  Place the type parameter on your `fs` reference:

```
Comparator<Integer> fs = Collections.reverseOrder(rs);
```

The cast is unnecessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem does not come from the cast but from the generic parameter of the Comparator

```
//This one is not parameterized
Comparator fs=(Comparator<Integer>)Collections.reverseOrder(rs); // Same result with casting or without casting
Collections.sort(ts,fs)
```

Replace with

```
Comparator<Integer> fs=(Comparator<Integer>)Collections.reverseOrder(rs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Comparator<Integer> fs = Collections.reverseOrder(rs);`.